# GitLab cloning not successful

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

Gitlab is up and running on a private server. I can access the repo through the web portal and commit a readme file, etc to a project that I am a master of. But I am not able to clone the repository on my local machine, either through SSH or through https URLs. The error I see for SSH is

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

And for HTTPS is:

> Cloning into 'kktest1'... fatal: unable to access
>   'http://127.0.1.1/koushik/kktest1.git/': Failed to connect to
>   127.0.1.1 port 80: Operation timed out

I have set up the SSH key as instructed and added the same in the web portal under my profile.

VERY new to gitlab, completely lost. Please help?!

Comment: What's the command you are using for cloning in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A completely stupid mistake. I had to replace the local host IP(127.0.1.1) with my actual host IP because the gitlab is setup in a remote server! And I can clone now.

Thanks for the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

Go to your project homepage, and ensure that the dropdown underneath the title has SSH selected. then clone using the SSH URL displayed. If that doesn't work, check your SSH agent has the key loaded. If so, you probably have a firewall running that blocks the required port